# Is it possible for a the host to authenticate to a KDC running on a Docker container?

Tags: docker, active-directory, kerberos

I have a setup where an MIT Kerberos KDC is running on a Docker container. I am running this on a Windows 10 machine with Docker for Windows.

container hostname: quickstart.cloudera 
my computer's hostname: computer.example.internal

The KDC is setup properly in the container and I am able authenticate using `kinit`. I want to authenticate my host machine to the same KDC. I ran this command on: `ksetup /addkdc quickstart.cloudera`, but when I call `kinit` from Windows, it is unable to find the KDC. I realize that the container's domain is not the same as the host, but the container is configured to run with that name, so I can't do much there. Is there any way I can make this setup work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not set this up myself but in order for a `kinit` call to be successful

1. DNS must be in place and host name resolution must be working
   properly and
2. you'll need to configure a `C:\Windows\krb5.ini` file in order for the
   Kerberos client as well. On Windows, this file does not exist by
   default.

Please refer to this MIT reference for how to properly set up the `krb5.ini`, replacing in the actual host names, domain, and realm values of your network for the examples shown throughout the file: [Sample krb5.conf File](http://web.mit.edu/KERBEROS/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-admin/Sample-krb5_002econf-File.html)